# UIKit coordinate system, how does it work?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have a rectangular-shaped button in my Xcode project. I am using objective C, and I want to change the position of this button in objective C. The thing that is confusing is that, is the point made by the x and y axis is the point on the top left of the button, in the center of the button, or something completely different?

Also, how do I position a button through code(e.g if I have a button named *button*, then should the code be like
*button*.center = CGPointMake(x,y)?)

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH2-SW15

Comment: you want to center your button on view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain step b step:

Origin is a point where your button start, where center is the center of your button

1- CGRect(x,y,width,height) x and y are points where you button start. For example if x and y are 0 you button will start at the beginning of the screen. If x = 10 and y = 0, the button will start 10 points to the right, and 0 points down.

Example: button.frame = CGRectMake(10,20,100,100); this will make a button of width 100 points and height 100 points that start from 10 point to the right, 20 points to te bottom.

2- CGPointMake(x,y) you can give the button a center like this,

Example: button.center = CGPointMake(100,100);

this will make the center of the button is 100 points to the right and 100 points down. Keep in mind you are setting the center here and not the origin.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the frame of UIButton :

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

This will set your button's top left corner in x,y point